# Why does relativedelta remove more than 1 month when i do months=-1?

Tags: python, python-dateutil

I have the last day of the month, in this case 30th June 2020, and I am trying to change it to 1st June 2020. What I did is this

```
end_date + relativedelta(days=+1, months=-1)
```

but what it returns is May 31st 2020, when I want June 1st 2020. I realised the error comes from months=-1, which returns May 30th by itself, but shouldn't it return May 31st, since I am subtracting 1 month from June 30th? I thought relativedelta was able to tell which months have 31 days and which have 30 days?

Comment: If you have a date in a month and want to get the first of that month, isn't it easier to just `end_date.replace(day=1)`?

Comment: oh yes, hahah did not think about that, thank you!